# Trying to Add Customer Attribute in Magento 2.1

Tags: attributes, magento2

Getting pretty frustrated with this not working.

I have tried following multiple tutorials on how to do this but none of them are working.

Running Magento 2.1.5.

I am simply trying to create a customer attribute. my `Setup/UpgradeData.php` script is as follows:

namespace Wildcard\CustomerMods\Setup;

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface   $context
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "customer_payment_type");

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "customer_payment_type", array(
            "type"     => "varchar",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Payment Type",
            "input"    => "select",
            "source"   => 'Wildcard\CustomerMods\Model\Config\Source\Customer\PaymentTypeOptions',
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => true,
            "default"  => "",
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"   => false,
            "note"     => ""

        ));

        $my_attribute    = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, ' customer_payment_type');
        $used_in_forms[] = "adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[] = "customer_account_edit";
        $my_attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                     ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                     ->setData("is_system", 0)
                     ->setData("is_user_defined", 0)
                     ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                     ->setData("sort_order", 100);
        $my_attribute->save();
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I have tried increasing the version number in my `module.xml`. This is picked up in the `setup_module` table but it just refuses to create the attribute! I am looking in the admin area (new customer and edit customer) and in the `eav_attribute` table in the database. The attribute is not appearing in either.

Is there something wrong with the code above?

It would be great to see some debug info from Magento about this but there is nothing at all in the logs.

Please can someone help out with this? I'm just about pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

Following code will create a customer attribute, you can compare it with your code. (working code on Magento 2.1.5 )

**app/code/Jworks/CustomerSetup/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 *
 * @category    Jworks
 * @package     Jworks_CustomerSetup
 * @author Jitheesh V O <jitheeshvo@gmail.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2017 Jworks Digital (/)
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jworks_CustomerSetup" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Jworks/CustomerSetup/registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @category    Jworks
 * @package     Jworks_CustomerSetup
 * @author Jitheesh V O <jitheeshvo@gmail.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2017 Jworks Digital (/)
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Jworks_CustomerSetup',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Jworks/CustomerSetup/Setup/UpgradeData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Upgrade Data setup Script
 * @category    Jworks
 * @package     Jworks_CustomerSetup
 * @author Jitheesh V O <jitheeshvo@gmail.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2017 Jworks Digital (/)
 */
namespace Jworks\CustomerSetup\Setup;


use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var IndexerRegistry
     */
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    protected $eavConfig;


    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
    )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.1.0', '<')) {

            $this->upgradeVersionZeroOneZero($customerSetup);
        }
        $indexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get(Customer::CUSTOMER_GRID_INDEXER_ID);
        $indexer->reindexAll();
        $this->eavConfig->clear();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * @param $customerSetup
     */
    private function upgradeVersionZeroOneZero($customerSetup)
    {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_payment_type',
            [
                "type" => "varchar",
                "backend" => "",
                "label" => "Payment Type",
                "input" => "text",
                "visible" => true,
                "required" => true,
                "default" => "",
                "frontend" => "",
                "unique" => false,
                "note" => ""
            ]
        );
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_payment_type');
        $attribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']

        )
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 0)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```